# I am looking to generate a list of Concrete nouns....with picture and associated sentence

Tags: c#, java, android, python, dictionary

I am looking to generate programmaticaly a list of concrete nouns, an associated picture and if possible a sentence describing the proper noun.

I have tried various dictionary APIs - but the first part of the problem - getting a list of concrete nouns has caused me difficulty. Can anybody think of a good way of achieving this I would be very interested in hearing about it!

Please be aware I know what hashmaps are - and storing this data is not my problem - more sourcing the data is what I need help with - WHERE do I get a list of concrete nouns I can progrmmatically iterate over.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please define the term "proper" for your context?

Comment: By proper I mean the true english definition of a proper noun - Cat, Dog, Japan, House, etc

Comment: It IS - I need to know what source, and how I can iterate over it - where would I ask this question if not here..it is essentially an API question.

Comment: You want a list of proper nouns based on something, or simply a list of ALL proper nouns?

Comment: a list of ALL proper nouns would be best - I see Jamie's answer below would be useful for the former...

Comment: This isn't suitable for SO. You are asking where you can find data, not only is it essentially a shopping list question, but it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Ok - so lets be a bit more constructive than that. It IS a programming question - as Jamie's answer below demonstrates. On top of that - your response is not helpful or constructive in anyway. If there is a better place for this question - point me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NLTK](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1091-how-to-use-an-nltk-part-of-speech-tagger/) has a part of speech tagger. You could run it on a piece of text and store all the nouns it identifies as your list.

If you want a list of all nouns, you might be in for a long hunt - you'd have to run through every dictionary, encyclopedia, atlas and baby names book in the English language. A more reasonable place to start would be this list of [2336 nouns](http://www.desiquintans.com/articles.php?page=nounlist) of various kinds. They reckon it's short of a complete list by 50,000 or so - and my bet is that's an underestimate.

Comment: This is a good post - But how I would i find text to feed into the system?

Comment: It depends. As you say in reply to @Bob Horn above, this is most useful if you have an area you want to focus on. By the way, only one of your examples is a proper noun (Japan). The rest are common nouns. I assume that you meant both common and proper nouns? Or did you mean concrete (as opposed to abstract) nouns - if you're looking for a picture to represent each of them?

Comment: Concrete in this case - I most likely mean all nouns...

Comment: Superb list - this is nearly exactly what I was looking for - and is a great place to start! Thank you ever so much! If other people have anything else to extend this - let me know!

Comment: Not strictly a programming question then ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to do in Java** 
You can use HashMap to store the data; where key can be proper noun and value an object which has other details

```
    HashMap<String, ProperNounObj> obj = new HashMap<String, ProperNounObj>();
    where ProperNounObj class has attributes like picutureUrl and description
```

List of proper noun can be generated by hashmap method obj.keySet(); this will return a set of all proper noun.

Comment: I know how to store the data - that is not what I am asking, I am asking how to SOURCE the information, where can I get the list...

Comment: your question was not clear initially...